# Any way to code import/export data in MS SQL Server 2012 without SSIS, openrowset, Linked surver or BCP?

Tags: sql-server

My organization does not allow linked servers, BCP, openrowset, or the SSIS service.

I need to import and export data between sql servers and sql servers to the PC file system (into excel files) on a regular basis.

Is there a way to do this without using the import/export Wizard? I think I have exhausted all the other alternatives...

Comment: sqlcmd; detach/reattach; backup/restore; .NET's System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy (et al); Excel VBA + ODBC

Answer (score 2):

Use power shell.

This snippet dumps data from adventureworks2012.person.person to a pipe delimited file.  Comma delimited files are recognized by MS Excel.

Many other things power shell can do.

```
1 - create directories
2 - date time stamp files
3 - move files to archive directories
4 - zip files
5 - ftp files
```

The limit is only how much you are willing to learn.

Here is an article on "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel".  Unfortunately, the MS Office products are not re-written in managed code (.NET) yet.

http://import-powershell.blogspot.com/2012/03/excel-part-1.html

```
# ******************************************************
# *
# * Name:         dump-sql-query-to-delimited-file.ps1
# *     
# * Design Phase:
# *     Author:   John Miner
# *     Date:     01-09-2014
# *     Purpose:  Given a sql query, store the data
# *               in a delimited file.
# * 
# ******************************************************

# Debug script?
[string]$debug = "T"

# Debug info
if ($debug -eq "T")
{
    Write-Host "Starting [dump-sql-query-to-delimited-file]";
};


# Set these variables
[string]$server = ".";
[string]$database = "AdventureWorks2012";
[string]$query = "SELECT TOP 10 FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Person";
[string]$file = "C:\temp\data.txt"
[string]$delimiter = "|"

# Create connection
$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Server=" + $server + "; Database=" + $database + ";Integrated Security=true;";

# Create command
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$cmd.CommandText = $query;
$cmd.Connection = $con;

# Create adapter
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$da.SelectCommand = $cmd;

# Fill DataTable 
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$da.Fill($dt) | Out-Null;

# Close connection
$con.close();

# Dump the data
$dt | Export-CSV -delimiter $delimiter -Path $file;


# Debug detailed info
if ($debug -eq "T")
{
  Write-Host;
  foreach ($row in $dt.rows)
  {
    for ($i=0;$i -lt $row.ItemArray.Count; $i++) 
    {  Write-Host $row.Table.Columns[$i].ToString() = $row.ItemArray[$i]  };
    Write-Host;
  };
}

# Debug info
if ($debug -eq "T")
{
    Write-Host "Ending [dump-sql-query-to-delimited-file]";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Various routines can be implemented and loaded as CLR assemblies.  However, I'd wager that your organization does not allow the CLR to be enabled...

Answer (score 0):

Having to do ETL without being allowed to use any ETL tools sucks.  I have a CLR for exporting .xml workbooks which can be opened by management-types in Excel from SQL Server 2005+ databases if you'd like to have a look at it, but nothing already on-hand for import.  Sounds like you're going to be having a ton of fun with your new project.

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_ExcelGenerator 
    @FileName = '\\<some unc path if you''re lucky>\shared\',
    @Statement = 'SELECT  x = 1; SELECT  y = 2;',
    @SheetNames = 'SheetTest1, SheetTest2';
```

This assumes whatever overbearing policy management going on over there lets you install CLRs, of course.